# Dagger2 throw exception on MainActivityModule

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger

I setup the MVVM architecture with retrofit and dagger2 but when i run i found this exception

> error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError]
>   dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this
>   interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check
>   for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

AppModule.java

```
@Module(subcomponents = ViewModelSubComponent.class)
public class AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
ApiService provideService(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseRequest.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create(ApiService.class);
}


@Provides
CompositeDisposable provideCompositeDisposable() {
    return new CompositeDisposable();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public StethoInterceptor getSteltho() {
    return new StethoInterceptor();
}


@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Application application, StethoInterceptor stethoInterceptor, HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpClient.connectTimeout(CommonUtils.TIMEOUT_IN_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.readTimeout(CommonUtils.TIMEOUT_IN_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.addInterceptor(getIntercepter(application));
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        okHttpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(stethoInterceptor);
        okHttpClient.interceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    }

    return okHttpClient.build();
}


public Interceptor getIntercepter(final Application application) {

    Interceptor headerAuthorizationInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            if (!CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(application)) {
                Request request = chain.request();
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder().maxStale(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).build();
                request = request.newBuilder().cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
                String rawJson = chain.proceed(request).body().string();
                Log.e("TAG", String.format("req response cache raw JSON response is: %s", rawJson));
                return chain.proceed(request);
            } else {

                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build();
                Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder();
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                //request.addHeader("Authorization", mAuth);
                request.header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 90);
                request.header(CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString());
                Response response = chain.proceed(request.build());


                return response;
            }
        }
    };
    return headerAuthorizationInterceptor;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;
}


/*@Singleton
@Provides
ProjectRepository getrepository() {
    return new ProjectRepository();
}*/

@Singleton
@Provides
ViewModelProvider.Factory provideViewModelFactory(ViewModelSubComponent.Builder viewModelSubComponent) {
    return new ViewModelFactory(viewModelSubComponent.build());
}
```

MainActivityModule.java

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)
public abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity(); //  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)


}
```

FragmentBuildersModule.ktx

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuildersModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector
internal abstract fun contributeHomeFragment(): HomeFragment


//@ContributesAndroidInjector
//abstract SeriesFragment contributeSeriesFragment();

}
```

ViewModelFactory.java

```
@Singleton
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

private final ArrayMap<Class, Callable<? extends ViewModel>> creators;

@Inject
public ViewModelFactory(ViewModelSubComponent viewModelSubComponent) {
    creators = new ArrayMap<>();

    // View models cannot be injected directly because they won't be bound to the owner's view model scope.
    creators.put(ProjectViewModel.class, () -> viewModelSubComponent.homeViewModel());
  //  creators.put(ProjectListViewModel.class, () -> viewModelSubComponent.projectListViewModel());
}

@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
    Callable<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
    if (creator == null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class, Callable<? extends ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                creator = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (creator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class " + modelClass);
    }
    try {
        return (T) creator.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, MainActivityModule.class})//, MainActivityModule.class
 public interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);


    AppComponent build();

}

void inject(MyApplication appApplication);

}
```

AppInjector.java

```
public class AppInjector {

private static Application application;

private AppInjector() { }

public static void init(MyApplication appApplication) {
    application = appApplication;
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(appApplication).build().inject(appApplication);

    appApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            handleActivity(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
}

private static void handleActivity(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(activity);
    }
    if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
        ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment fragment, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        if (fragment instanceof Injectable) {
                            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(fragment);
                        }
                    }
                }, true);
    }
}

}
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

private static PrefManager mPref;

private static MyApplication myApplication;
private Context context;
//private String dbUrl = "";

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;


public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return myApplication == null ? new MyApplication() : myApplication;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.context = this;


    MultiDex.install(this);
    AppInjector.init(this);
    Fresco.initialize(this);

    RemoteConfig.initConfig();



    mPref = new PrefManager(this);
    debugToolsInitilization();


}

@Override
public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
}
```

Throw exception when i add MainActivityModule module

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Would you mind taking a look at a different approach? It works seamlessly for multiple Dagger modules getting injected.  Each dagger module targeted for specific group of dependency. Sample is here. https://github.com/sreeharikv112/MyCompany   You can find Dagger main configurations under package. src/main/java/com/myoffice/dipinject/

Comment: When i am add FragmentBuildersModule throw exception can u tell me why occure?                                                                                                                                    I am follow my own sample https://github.com/SamsetDev/Mvvm-android-master

Comment: I wont be able to go through that sample and dig into. But i'm pretty sure that the other github link which I sent is handling similar issues

Comment: i solve this issue if you also face this type of issue you should change in the component class. You just change your AndroidInjectionModule from AndroidSupportInjectionModule